# how to disable fields in tca only for certain ctypes

Tags: typo3

I want to disable certain fields in the backend, e.g. many fields of gridelements and other content elements. I know about the possibilities of TCEFORM but it allowes only to disable a field in all cTypes. I need a way to disable certain field only for certain cTypes.

Is there a way to achieve this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't need additional conditions like i.e. a certain user or group or a particular branch of the page tree to disable these fields, you should not go for PageTSconfig and TCEFORM but pure TCA types instead.

Just create a site package extension, which would be recommended anyway, and make sure to provide the desired setup for the tt_content table within Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php so it will be applied automatically.

You can find some slides about the "Anatomy of Sitepackages" here: https://de.slideshare.net/benjaminkott/typo3-the-anatomy-of-sitepackages

Additional information about the TCA types can be found here:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Types/Index.html

As Gridelements just provides mandatory fields for layout, children, container and column, you should not disable these fields though, since it might break the functionality.

Comment: Hi Joey, thanks for your answer. I was afraid that i has to rebuild most of the tca of tt_content :-) i will give it a try. I use gridelements only for multicolumn content so there is no need for fields like header, link, alignment, date, plugin options or the tabs appearence, categories or notes. Many customer are confused by these fields. Same in many other content elements.

Comment: For other users who read this thread: the example of jokumer works (i can only one answer mark as correct). You can get the needed text for "showitem" in the backend of TYPO3: go to "configuration", choose TCA, look for tt_content/types/your-cType/ and copy the showitem there. It is  mostly self explaining. Pretty time consuming for every content element but very easy.

Answer (score 3):

You have full control over which field are shown, if you adapt TCA for tt_content. You can override TCA with your customer extensions (sitepackage).

The following file contains fields, which are shown for CType *header* (TYPO3 CMS 7.6)

EXT:sitepackage/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die();

call_user_func(function () {
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['header']['showitem'] = '--palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,--palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.headers;headers,rowDescription,--div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance,--palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.frames;frames,--div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access,--palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.visibility;visibility,--palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,--div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.extended,--div--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category,categories';
});
```

Remove or add any fields after your needs and do so for any CType you wish to change.
See also https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Types/Index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works! I gave Joey the check for right answer, but your answer ist of course correct too. I tried your example with gridelements and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Meanwhile (since 9 LTS) it is possible via [TsConfig](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html#disabled):

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.subheader.types.text.disabled = 1
```

… disables the subheader field for all text content elements.

You can even disable a field for all cTypes and define an exception:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.subheader{
    disabled = 1
    types.text.disabled = 0
}
```