# How to hide database fields in TYPO3 backend

Tags: typo3

I have 3 use cases. All apply to already existing database fields from TYPO3. Changes should be made in the site package.

1. Hide field altogether, is not being used at all and should not clutter up forms in BE
2. Only available for admin, not for editor
3. Only available for admin and for editor if configured in BE group.

For number 3, I usually use the "[exclude](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Columns/Properties/Exclude.html)" field in TCA, this way the field can also be made available for the BE user. I guess could be used for number 2 as well (though this does clutter up the check boxes in the BE group section which is also an issue).

For number 1, I don't know if I should use TSconfig [disabled](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html#disabled).

I would like to do this directly in the site package, preferably via TCA.

Comment: Using TSconfig disabled is also accessible/understandable for integrators. Use TCA is IMO more in the scope of developers. So, maybe this is a criterion in projects.

Comment: @julian Thanks. That makes sense. Not sure what the corresponding TCA setting for TSConfig "disabled" is though. Searching for this kind of thing gets a lot of TSconfig examples - guess that is more intuitive and easy to use. Here is another question which overrides the entire showitem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019971/how-to-disable-fields-in-tca-only-for-certain-ctypes)  - looks a bit messy and error prone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer a solution based on PageTSconfig. Register a new PageTSconfig file in `TCA/Overrides/pages.php`:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::registerPageTSConfigFile(
    'sitepackage',
    'Configuration/TSconfig/Page.tsconfig',
    'Customer PageTSconfig'
);
```

After a Clear Cache you can select this file in page properties at tab Resources.

In this file we add entries like:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.disabled = 1
...
```

If you deactivate columns with TCA directly, an Integrator will not find the configuration and column name. That's why I prefer using PageTSconfig. That way an Integrator can go to BE module "Info" -> select PageTSconfig -> analyze which columns were disabled. With a little bit of copy and paste it's easy for an Integrator to activate that field again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For our usecase, I am looking for something for our sitepackage, which is already customized for our site - so there will be no integration necessary (the sitepackage is the integration). But I understand the way you explain, it makes it more flexible. Also, modifying the TSconfig looks simpler (than changing TCA).

Answer (score 1):

I always use TsConfig to hide elements because of the following reasons:

- If hidden by default for everybody, I know as integrator that this feature is not used in the whole project. In most projects, not every feature of content elements is needed and therefore also not styled in the frontend. I never run into the problem telling the customer "yeah there is a field for that" and I just enable it and forgetting any additional work to be done in the frontend
- It can be limited to usergroups
- It can be limited for parts of the tree

Comment: I don't quite understand your first point: If a field is to be always hidden (and never used), isn't that rather a reason to shut it off via TCA entirely? For the second 2 points that is good reason to make it configurable via TSconfig. (For my usecase we have some fields which are really not used at all.)

Comment: I don't want to mix configurations, having tca for removing and all other in tsconfig - therefore I do all in tsconfig